# how to return the index of max of each line using awk

Tags: awk

I have a file with many rows like this:

```
id  val1  val2  val3 val4
a  0.10  0.50  0.30  0.40
b  0.15  0.35  0.20  0.80
c  0.50  0.45  0.20  0.40
....
```

I want to output the index of the max value and also the max value of each row like this:

```
a val2 0.50
b val4 0.80
c val1 0.50
...
```

I used

```
awk '{m=$2;for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)if($i>m) m=$i;print $1,m}'
```

to output the max value, but not sure how to output its index (val# here) in the print command as well, thanks advance for any suggestions and ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are *almost* on the right track, just maintain a new variable `idx` for storing the index as

```
awk 'NR>1{m=$2;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>=m) { m=$i; idx=i }; print $1,"val"(idx-1),m}' file
```

will produce the output as you need. Also couple of points worth noting here 1) Skip the header line as it is not needed for processing `NR>1` takes care of that and 2) start your loop from `$2` and change the conditional to `($i>=m)` as it can match the 2nd column too.

Comment: That was fast !

Comment: @JamesBrown: For once! ;)

Answer (score 1):

Another for awk:

```
awk 'NR==1{split($0,a);next}{m=0;for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)if($i>m){m=$i;n=i}print $1,a[n],m}' foo
a val2 0.50
b val4 0.80
c val1 0.50
```